# method joptionpane.Showinputdialog arguments not applicable in processing

Tags: java, processing, arduino-uno

I am new to arduino programming . This is a gctrl code in the processing software. I am getting this error **"the method showInputDialog(Component,Object,String,int,Icon,Object[],Object) in the type jOptionPane is not applicable for arguments(gctrl,String,String,int,null,int,int)"** even though i have seen the same format of the arguments in the tutorials.

Here is the code.

```
void selectSerialPort(){  

String result = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,
 "Select the serial port that corresponds to your Arduino board.",
 "Select serial port",
 JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
 null,
 Serial.list(),
 0);

}
```

Comment: You even forgot the screen shot. But we dont want screen shots anyway. Please read [mcve] then add source code and errors as **formatted** text. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide your code and the error you get. Please copy the text in code sample instead of screenshot if it is possible.

Comment: @Arashsoft  i have provided the code and the error . Hope this is more clear

Answer (score 0):

The `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` function requires a component as the first argument. You're passing in `this` which refers to the Processing sketch. But as of Processing 3, sketches are not components: more specificlaly, the `PApplet` class no longer extends the `Applet` class.

You could try to get to the underlying `JFrame` by going through the `surface` variable and pass that in instead. Or you could just pass `null` in.

Taking a step back, it's a little weird to use Swing from a Processing sketch. Instead of showing an error dialog (which users hate anyway), show a friendly error message inside the Processing sketch itself.